# Deactive onchange event only when Enter key is pressed in Internet explore

Tags: jquery

```js
$("#name").on("change", funName);

$("#name").on("keypress", function(e){

    if(e.which == 13){
   
        funName(e);
    
    }

});

function funName(e){
            alert("funName");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
```

I am calling on change event when textbox is changing. I have written keypress event only for enter key because change event is not firing when i press enter key in internet explore. So now my probleam when i pressed enter key its calling two times funcation funName. one time from keypress event for enter key and one time from change event for mouse click outside of textbox. I would like to stop calling change event when i press enter key.

````
```<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>

$("#name").on("change", funName);

$("#name").on("keypress", function(e){

    if(e.which == 13){
  
        funName();
    }

});

function funName(){
    alert("function calling");
}```
````

Comment: Please provide more code to get a Minimal Reproducile Code as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you...I have added code snippet. After typing something in textbox press enter key. Now function "funName" is fired two times.  I would like to prevent change event calling function "funName" only when enter key is pressed.

Comment: I am calling ajax call in function "funName" so when i pressed enter key then its calling two times ajax call.Thank you.